# I have a table and i resultant output as I shown in description

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I have created the table emp_workout and it has 6 records which is shown below

```
empid | empname | Tax   | Aadhar
------|---------|-------|------
  1   | Raja    | 12000 | null
  1   | Raja    | 4000  | null
  2   | Bhasker | 11000 | null
  2   | Bhasker | 4000  | null
  1   | Raja    | 4000  | null
  1   | Raja    | 4000  | 456ASBDD
```

And I need a query to print the output as like below

```
empid |  empname | Total_tax | Aadhar   | Aadhar
------|--------- |-----------|----------|--------
  1   |  Raja    |  24000    | 456ASBDD |   Y
  2   |  Bhasker |  15000    |  null    |   N
```

I have tried groupby

```
empid  | empname  | total_tax |   Aadhar  | nvl2(aadhar)
-------| -------- |-----------|-----------|--------------
   1   |  Raja    |  20000    |  null     |    N
   1   |  Raja    |  4000     | 456ASBDD  |    Y
   2   |  Bhasker |  15000    |   null    |    N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a convenient function [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm#OLADM625) that does this simply:

```
SELECT empid, empname, SUM(Tax) as Total_tax,
       MAX(Aadhar) as Aadhar_value,
       NVL2(MAX(Aadhar), 'Y', 'N') as Aadhar
FROM emp_workout
GROUP BY empid, empname;
```

It is like `COALESCE()` but it takes three arguments -- the value to test, the value to return when `NOT NULL` and the value to return when `NULL`.

This is an Oracle extension.  The `CASE` expression is standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT empid,empname,
SUM(Tax)Total_tax,
MAX(Aadhar) Aadhar_value,
CASE
    WHEN MAX(Aadhar) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END Aadhar
FROM emp_workout
GROUP BY empid,empname
```